# My id=x is just showing all content?

Tags: php, mysql

I finally learned how to do it
but the problem is that when i click lol.php?id=2 it still shows all content
here the source:

```
<?php

   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   mysql_select_db("blog");

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT post_id, title, body FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC");

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $jokeid = $row["post_id"];
      $title = $row["title"];
      $body = $row["body"];
      echo("<A HREF='lol.php?view=$jokeid'>$title</A>". "<br />". $body . "<br />");
   }
   mysql_close();
?>
```

and any security advice, where should i apply mysql_reall_escape_string here ?

Comment: What is the source of `lol.php`?

Comment: @Smamatti: no. It isn't required

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any handler of user's input, try something like below, which will check whether `id=NUMBER` is set first

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("blog");
if ($_GET['id']) {
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT  title, body FROM posts WHERE post_id = ".intval($_GET['id']));
   $post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   // use $post to show whatever you want here
}
else{
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT post_id, title, body FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC");

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $jokeid = $row["post_id"];
     $title = $row["title"];
     $body = $row["body"];
     echo("<A HREF='lol.php?view=".$jokeid."'>".$title."</A>". "<br />". $body . "<br />");
   }
}
mysql_close();
```

Comment: i thikn now its fixed or its showing an error since it gives: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lol.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the database variables for output using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$title = htmlspecialchars($row["title"]);
$body = htmlspecialchars($row["body"]);
echo("<A HREF='lol.php?view=$jokeid'>$title</A>". "<br />". $body . "<br />");
```

This prevents the possibility of cross-site scripting if the database was filled by user-input.

Comment: This isn't required, if he wants to use html in his articles

Comment: ok thank u but what about that id=1 id=2 id=3 shows like lol.php